# GTM - tracking latest input click value

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager

**My script**

```
function() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
      selectedRadios = [];
  for (var i = 0;i < inputs.length;i++) {
    if(inputs[i].type==="checkbox" && inputs[i].checked) {
      selectedRadios.push(inputs[i].value);
    }
  }
  return selectedRadios;
}
```

This script returns an array of all the checked buttons value. So, in my case, if I check three inputs the array will be for example: [167,168,169]

**Issue**: The array is auto sorted in ascending numerical order, while I want that the array is sorted based on which one was checked first, second, third,... .

To do that I edited the script above in this way

```
function() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
      selectedRadios = [],
      selectedRadios_latestchoice = [];

  // get all checkboxs selected
  for (var i = 0;i < inputs.length;i++) {
    if(inputs[i].type==="checkbox" && inputs[i].checked) {
      selectedRadios.push({filterValue : inputs[i].value, latestchoice : selectedRadios.length});
    }
  }

  // sort value by last choice
  selectedRadios.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.latestchoice - b.latestchoice;
    }),
      
  // parse data 
  var obj = JSON.parse(selectedRadios),

    for (var s = 0;s < obj.length;s++) {
      selectedRadios_latestchoice.push(obj[s].filterValue);
  }

  // return last value of the array "selectedRadios_latestchoice"
  return selectedRadios_latestchoice[selectedRadios_latestchoice.length];
}
```

The logic is:

- push the "input value" and the "array.length",
  *the "array.length" tell me if the input value was clicked first, second, third ..*
- sort the input value by the array.length value.
- parse the json.
- return the latest value of the array.

My attempt return an error. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more eligant way to do this, but I was able to use a forEach loop with a nested event listener running a function. In the function we run the ***event.target*** through a conditional that checks `e.target.checked`, if this returns true we push the value into an array, we then reduce that array creating an obj that saves the ***arr.length*** as ***property*** and the ***current value*** as ***value***. Then we push that object into a final array to force the key from auto sorting.

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.check')

let val = []
const keyValPair = []

checkboxes.forEach((value) => {
  value.addEventListener('change', getPositionAndValue)
})

function getPositionAndValue(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    val.push(e.target.value)
    var result = val.reduce(function(result, curr) {
      result[val.length] = curr;
      return result;
    }, {})
    keyValPair.push(result)

    console.log(keyValPair)
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="check" value="167" type="checkbox">
<input class="check" value="168" type="checkbox">
<input class="check" value="169" type="checkbox">
<input class="check" value="170" type="checkbox">
<input class="check" value="171" type="checkbox">
```